# 301 redirect for index.html and all http,https, www and non-www version of homepage URL to https://www root url via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect

I want to 301 redirect the following URL’s via htaccess file

Which means I need to force SSL(https) version and force the www across the whole website.

In addition I also want to 301 redirect the index.html to the https and www version of the homepage url.

I want to 301 redirect the following urls:

```
https://www.example.com/index.html
https://example.com/index.html
https://example.com
http://www.example.com/index.html
http://example.com/index.html
http://www.example.com
http://example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

To

```
“https://www.example.com”
```

In addition to that I need all urls of the site to be redirected to https://www version like this:

```
“https://www.example.com/new-site.html”
```

Heres what I am using right now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```

But the above rules seem to give me a 301--->302-----200 ok redirect for 2 url's with /index.html and 301 for the rest.

It gives a 302 from:

```
“https://www.example.com/index.html”
```

To this

```
“https://www.example.com/“
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do add clear details samples of URLs like from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite, by wrapping them inside CODE TAGS for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Sorry I will edit this

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile and don't have full functionality.

Comment: Comments are not meant to show question/efforts, as requested previously please update your question, thank you.

Comment: It wont let me post more than 8 links even if they are example.com links

Comment: may be you are missing CODE TAGS that's why its not allowing it, try with CODE TAGS around links or your htaccess file in your question.

Comment: Can you paste a code tag in here so i can copy it and use it wont let me use it <>

Comment: See `https://www.website.com` this in your question how it looks like now, wrap them with backticks.

Comment: Thanks. Done now. Phew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all this in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?:^|(.+)/)(?:index\.html)?$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank You, I’ll check this one out as well.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn’t redirect the index.html to the <https:// www> root url.

Comment: This works but adds trailing slash at the end of url's. Is it possible to remove trailing slash ?

Comment: Yes sure, check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks... I tried it, its the same result: with the trailing slash

Comment: If `$1` points to a real directory then a trailing slash is added by Apache `mod_dir` module for security reasons. Why do you want to remove a `/` from a directory request URI?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out myself:

Here's how it will work, just needed to add R=301 in the last rule and not just R

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```